# hibernate query with group by, distinct, count more than one column

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

i want to create query in hibernate given below

- select distinct uid, count(attlabid) from attlab where year='BE' and sub='c++' group by uid;

it is giving 2 columns as result in postgresql -
 1) uid (int)
 2) count (bigint)

but in hibernate i need same output in hibernate but itz not getting worked

```java
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session s1 = sf.openSession();
        s1.beginTransaction();
        String str="select distinct uid, count(attlabid) from attlab where year='BE' and sub='c++' group by uid";
        Query q1 = s1.createQuery(str);
        List<AttLab> l1 = (List<AttLab>) q1.list();
        s1.getTransaction().commit();
        s1.close();
        out.println("result :"+ l1);
```

it not exicuting query i thin it is because AttLab tables column dont have count column... i am not getting how to achieve this..

Comment: You should use createSQLQuery() for SQL queries. createQuery() uses HQL.